# Error after installing extension

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

I am getting error after installing the extension [extension link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/search-autocomplete-search-suggest.html)

Error follows

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getReadConnection() on a non-object in /home/ppdeec/public_html/bigzaar.com/includes/src/__default.php on line 31647
```

Anybody knows how to fix this. any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disbale compilation mode and try

To disable compilation go to your magento root edit `includes/config.php`

At around line 28, uncomment the first line and comment out the second:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');

define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Comment: may it cause any other problems?

Comment: no it dosent create any problem @SibyThomas